# using the newline character on windows

Tags: erlang

I've been having problems with the ~n in erlang, been trying for 2 days to write a list of data to a file, io:format(file, "~s~n", [X]).

of course i have tried using map and foreach to iterate through the list but still i am getting everything on 1 line instead of a newline character. the list is a list of lines read from a different file. This is a windows OS.

am I missing something? is there some alternative for doing this on windows? I've been reading many tutorials and asked here for help before but I'm beginning to think there is no solution for me :/ some very simple task in any other language, even haskell can do it.

I can print the list to the console and it will appear just as the text i read. but when i write this list to a file it appears all in 1 line. so:

```
blah
blah
blah
```

becomes

```
blah blah blah
```

And i cant get around this :(

Answer (score 0):

Windows newlines are `\r\n` (carraige-return and newline).

Try:

```
io:format(File, "~s\r\n", [X]).
```

Comment: printing to the console works fine, with all methods. but the problem is when i print to a file :/ also ~s\r\n does not do the trick :(

Comment: how you write info to file?Proposed version working.

Comment: To write to a file, look at: [`file:write/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#write-2) or [`file:write_file/[2,3]`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#write_file-2), the former writes to an open file descriptor, the latter writes the provided contents to the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you have (in your example):

```
Data = ["blah", "blah", "blah"].
```

Then:

```
io:format(File, "~s\r\n", [string:join(Data, "\r\n")]).
```

will do what you want on Windows.
Frankly "~n" is supposed to be platform-dependent, but it isn't working for my version of Erlang, so the "\r\n" is necessary, i.e.

```
io:format(File, "~s~n", [string:join(Data, "\n")]).
```

should work, but doesn't.